# macOS: Problem moving child window with Parent window

Tags: objective-c, macos, parent-child, nswindow

I have written a sample code in objective-c to draw two windows and making the first window the parent of 2nd window, so that when first window is moved, second window also moves. I can see two windows are drawn, but the child window is not moving when I move the parent window. What is wrong with this code?

```
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
NSUInteger styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask;
NSRect rect = [NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame styleMask:styleMask];

NSWindow * window =  [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:styleMask backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered    defer:false];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

NSRect frame1 = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
NSUInteger styleMask1 =  NSTitledWindowMask;
NSRect rect1 = [NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame1 styleMask:styleMask1];

NSWindow * window1 =  [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect1 styleMask:styleMask1 backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered    defer:false];
[window1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
[window1 makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

CFRunLoopRun();
[window1 setParentWindow:window];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1:

`setParentWindow` isn't executed. `CFRunLoopRun`:

> Runs the current thread’s CFRunLoop object in its default mode indefinitely.

Set the parent window before `CFRunLoopRun`.

Issue 2:

From the documentation of `parentWindow`:

> This property should be set from a subclass when it is overridden by a subclass’s implementation. It should not be set otherwise.

Use `addChildWindow:ordered:` instead.

```
[window addChildWindow:window1 ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

Comment: Tried that. Still same behavior.

Comment: It solved the problem. But I have a question...would it also work for existing windows? I want to finally make my application child of the Google Chrome. For that, I have retrieved the Window ID of Google Chrome and my application and using same `addChildWindow` function to reparent it...but it is not working as the above example working now.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated the parent <-> child relationship must be present in order to let the child windows "follow" the parent.

In my case the problem was that the window was create, hidden with `orderOut` and then shown again.
 **You should never call `orderOut` on a child window because as stated in the official** [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419660-orderout?language=objc):

> Calling orderOut: on a child window causes the window to be removed
> from its parent window before being removed.

So when the window is shown again the parent <-> child relationship is no more present and the child window is not moved when the parent moves.

Also note that invoking `setIsVisible` and passing it **FALSE** will internally trigger a call to `orderOut`.

So **if you just want to hide the window** without loosing the relationship with the parent you can call

```
[window setAlphaValue:0];
[window setViewsNeedDisplay:TRUE];
```